# Excel Cell Selection shows count instead of sum for a time value in hh:mm:ss format

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I have used phpspreadsheet package for exporting a report. I have write the column values(time value in `hh:mm:ss`) using the function `setCellValueByColumnAndRow` and formatted the cell value using `setFormatCode function`.

After downloading I have selected some specific cells vertically it shows the count of number of cells selected instead of sum of the cell values in time.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

```
            $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($cellValues[0], $current_row, $val['username']);
            $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($cellValues[1], $current_row, $val['date']);
            $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($cellValues[2], $current_row, $jobTimeTaken);
            $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($cellValues[3], $current_row, $breakTimeTaken);


$sheet->getStyle('G4')
      ->getNumberFormat()
      ->setFormatCode( \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME4);

$sheet->getStyle('G5')
      ->getNumberFormat()
      ->setFormatCode(                     \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME4);
```

Comment: That is simply a count of the number of rows selected. I don't see anything in your code that is trying to `sum` that column or display the result of that sum.

Comment: When we enter data manually into the excel cells with hh:mm:ss format and we select those it will give the count of the number of rows selected, sum of the selected cell value and average value of the selected cell. But the data entered using php Spreadsheet package does't show the sum and average for the cell selected it only show the count of the number of rows selected. I have tried with the sum formula in excel but that is also not provided the sum value it return the sum as 00:00:00. I have double clicked the cells individually and tried the aforesaid steps it works as expected.

Comment: I have copied the whole column and pasted into a new sheet in excel and it is also does not produce the sum value, but while copy and paste  the whole column into notepad++ and copied and paste into a sheet then its works fine and displaying the sum value in cell selection as well as in formula.

Comment: Nothing in Excel that I've ever seen would sum a group of cells and average them without formulas of some sort being applied. Excel can't possibly know what you want to do with a group of cells that you have selected without you telling it WHAT you want to do.

Comment: I have tried with excel formula for calculating sum of the cell values using =SUM(A2:A5) then also it producing the result 00:00:00.

Comment: Sorry but I can not duplicate the problem you are having. I entered the 4 values in your question into a new spreadsheet and used `SUM` on them and the result was the expected value `02:14`.